# Gitlab backup secrets

Tags: backup, gitlab

I have docker ce v9.3.5 running inside a docker container.

I want to backup gitlab secrets as descrited [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/backups.html#creating-backups-for-gitlab-instances-in-docker-containers)

I used this command to perform the backup of the secrets and configuration, but it gave me an error:

```
docker exec -t <your container name> /bin/sh -c 'umask 0077; tar cfz /secret/gitlab/backups/$(date "+etc-gitlab-\%s.tgz") -C / etc/gitlab'
```

[image]

I am not sure if the documentation is updated or my docker version is outdated, but looks like there is no **"/secret/gitlab/backups"** folder inside the container.

My question is:

1) which command do I need to run exactly?

1) can i just copy the container folder "/etc/gitlab" , which includes gitlab-secrets.json?

ps: I do have volumes mounted at "/etc/gitlab" , "/var/log/gitlab" and "/var/opt/gitlab"

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that gitlab_rails['backup_path'] option is indeed /secret/gitlab/backups/ and the path exists.
The idea is that if you set an different folder for backups then you will have to adjust the command as you have it set in gitlab configuration